# Deployment Workbench change language of the PE

Tags: wds

We've just started using the Microsoft Deployment Workbench and Windows Deployment Services to roll out a bunch of desktops.

The basics seem to be going well, but I have a question about the first GUI option, which is the "Microsoft Solution Accelerator" screen where you have the option of "Run Deployment Wizard" and "Command Prompt".

There is a drop-down box there for keyboard language, which seems to only be used for authentication to the Deployment Share, but I can't work out how to change this default to UK.

[image]

My current Bootstrap.ini on the Deployment Share properties is this:

```
[Settings]
Priority=Default

[Default]
DeployRoot=\\HELPDESK\DeploymentShare$
InputLocale=0809:00000809
KeyboardLocale=0809:00000809
UserLocale=en-GB
UILanguage=en-GB
```

Answer (score 1):

Try editing the bootstrap.ini and add the keyboard locale.

KeyboardLocale=0809:00000809
 UserLocale=en-GB
 UILanguage=en-GB

Comment: Aah, thanks.  That goes in the [Settings] section, or the [Default]?

Comment: I believe it goes in the Default section.

Comment: Nope, didn't work.  I'll try in the Settings section and rebuild the share.

Comment: Try it with just the keyboard locale.

Answer (score 1):

you will need to change it in the XML file for that ID. That will change it.
 - I worked it out, whilst am trying to change the default location for the images am deploying, its all pointing to US
 - click on start, windows syst image manager, open the XML (correpsonding to the Task sequence ID)
 - and change settings there, there are few (about 3 or 4) entries under the Pre install environ PE for input locale and that will default it to English UK.
however, am stuck finding an answer to my issue !!!